# Jquery + jeditable table row edit multiple fields

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-plugins, jeditable

I am trying to figure out the way to edit a row of table by button with jquery and jeditable. 
My aim is to have a "edit" button which will change desired row cells to edit mode.

As per now I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addrowbutton").click(function() {
        $("#addrow").show();
    });
    $("#canceladd").click(function() {
        $("#addrow").hide();
    });
    $("#saveadd").click(function() {
        $("#message").text("Added").fadeOut(4000, function() {
            $(this).css('display','block').text("");
        });
        $("#addrow").hide();
    });
    $("#add_trade_form").submit(function() {
        process_details();
        return false;
    });
    function process_details() { 
        $("#add_trade_form").ajaxSubmit();
        return false;
    }
    $(".editlink").click(function() {
        var datapos = $(this).parent().parent().prevAll().length;
        var editpos = datapos + 1;

        $("#trades_table tbody tr:eq(" + datapos + ")").hide();
        $("#trades_table tbody tr:eq(" + editpos + ")").show();
    });

    $(".cancellink").click(function() {
        var editpos = $(this).parent().parent().prevAll().length;
        var datapos = editpos - 1;

        $("#trades_table tbody tr:eq(" + datapos + ")").show();
        $("#trades_table tbody tr:eq(" + editpos + ")").hide();
    });
    $(".savelink").click(function() { 
        var editpos = $(this).parent().parent().prevAll().length;
        var datapos = editpos - 1;

        $("#message").text("Saved...").fadeOut(4000, function() {
            $(this).css('display','block').text("");
        });
        $("#trades_table tbody tr:eq(" + datapos + ")").show();
        $("#trades_table tbody tr:eq(" + editpos + ")").hide();
    });

});
```

So:

- adding row appears and hides with a button
- edit row display and cancel as it should with values I want

Where I am lost now:

- how to take the new values from the inputs and pass them to the controller (multiple id, values) ... I use MVC. <= .savelink
- how to save the new row without refreshing the page but refresh the table with the new values <= #saveadd

Many thanks in advance for all the help.

Cheers,

/Jacek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend using [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)

Look at the demo examples and the editing examples.

They also have a [plugin for .NET](http://trirand.net/)

Comment: Wow, that is exactly what I am looking for. Many thanks for the tip, the plugin is amazing!!